# Error in starting tomcat 5.0 from cmd prompt "The system cannot find the file -Djava.endorsed.dirs=."

Tags: cmd, java-6, tomcat5

```
I am executing a web app which is in tomcat 5.0 web app folder

when i am trying to start tomcat 5.0

i am getting this error "The system cannot find the file -Djava.endorsed.dirs=.

 Below u can see the error i am getting:
**************************************************************
i am already set my JAVA_HOME to c>program files>java>jdk>bin

and in system varaibles i added ;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin to path

i have jdk1.6.0_14 and below a jre7 folder.
```

But my tomcat 5.0 is starting in eclipse IDE without any trouble. i have done all the  known steps by me

```
help me friends!!
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbyoj.jpg): http://postimg.org/image/sfpfw4b97/[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

hey guys got rectified the problem

we need to set

JAVA_HOME to upto c>programmfiles>java>jdk

and path to c>programmfiles>java>jdk>bin

note down the difference ..

happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JAVA_HOME if being set inside a command prompt will not suffice as the tomcat app is opened in new prompt and will not inherit the env variables.

Solution: Add below keys to the advanced settings variable in the System:

```
1. Path: JAVA_HOME\bin
2. JAVA_HOME: Path to your JDK
```